# How to use one of the tuple return values from a function in a nested elif in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, return-value

```
def test():
    return(True, '123')

items = test()
```

I need to use return value of `items[0]` as a test condition in a nested else if statement. How do I do it at the else if statement?

Comment: Umm, you just refer to `items[0]`.  That's it.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you considered referring to `items[0]` by calling it `items[0]`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer... but discover test()[0] seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## this syntax works without requiring a handle

if a > b:
do task
elif test()[0]:
do task

Answer (score 0):

```
if items[0] ...:
  ...
```

Just refer to it as `items[0]`, it has the same indexing manner as a list.